# searching for errors in my random number generator

Tags: java, random

i'm supposed to be creating a "game" that assigns a random number and allows user to guess the number, it is then supposed to display the amount of guesses made.
just wondering what i'm missing since I cant currently get it to compile...
wouldn't mind having my errors pointed out.

```
    // ---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7
    // 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class RandomNumbersGame
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

       int low = 1;
       int max = 100;
       int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - low + 1) + low;
       Random rand = new Random();
       return randomNumber;

       String guessCount = 1;
       int userNumber;


       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       userNumber = keyboard.nextInt();



       while (userNumber != randomNumber)

       if (userNumber > randomNumber)
       {
          System.out.println("Too high, try again.");
       }
       else (userNumber < randomNumber)
       {
          System.out.println("Too low, guess again.");
       }

       else (userNumber == randomNumber)
       {
          System.out.println("It took you " + "of guesses.");  
       }

      }               
    }
```

Comment: What are the compilation errors? We are not compilers.

Comment: statements under `return randomNumber;` are not illegal. Unreachable codes.

Comment: sorry thought I included it the errors im getting are these, missing a brace, somewhere? NumbersGame.java:45: error: not a statement
         else (userNumber < randomNumber)
              ^
RandomNumbersGame.java:45: error: ';' expected
         else (userNumber < randomNumber)
                                         ^
RandomNumbersGame.java:50: error: not a statement
      else (userNumber == randomNumber)
           
RandomNumbersGame.java:50: error: ';' expected
      else (userNumber == randomNumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int low = 1;
    int max = 10;

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - low + 1) + low;
    int guessCount = 1;
    int userNumber;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess number = ");
        userNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        if (userNumber > randomNumber) {
            guessCount++;
            System.out.println("Too high, try again.");
        }
        else if (userNumber < randomNumber) {
            guessCount++;
            System.out.println("Too low, guess again.");
        }

        else if (userNumber == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("It took you " + guessCount + " times of guesses.");
        }
    } while (userNumber != randomNumber);

}
```

I think you would like to test as above. 100 is too many for guess :D

Comment: Don't you think you should lead him to the solution instead of pasting complete code?

Comment: @BenWin yes ! you are right sir. I think he also need to test complete code. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to keep track of your opening/closing brackets. Furthermore you have to put the readKey-functionality **inside** your while loop or you'll end up checking the same value over and over. Try something like

```
while(userNumber != randomNumber) {
    userNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(userNumber > randomNumber) {
    }
    else if(userNumber < randomNumber) {
    }
    else if(userNumber == randomNumber) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

You have to take care of the if-statement syntax, if you want to check for multiple conditions.

Furthermore you should read about **method signatures** and **return statements** because

```
return randomNumber;
```

doesn't make sense at all.

Last point is about datatypes:

```
String guessCount = 1;
```

should be:

```
int guessCount = 1;
```

If you want to print it afterwards you simply convert it to a `string`

Comment: you know it throws me of when you guys place the braces at the end of a line...lol

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issue:

1> The return statement is not valid for `public static void main(String[] args)`. The return type is void. I didn't understand what you are trying to achive with `Random`. So can't fixed. It also has multiple issue

2> You are trying to condition after else. That is not correct. If you want to check you can either check by multiple `if` statement like this.

```
if (userNumber > randomNumber)
{
     System.out.println("Too high, try again.");
}
if (userNumber < randomNumber)
{
      System.out.println("Too low, guess again.");
}

if (userNumber == randomNumber)
{
      System.out.println("It took you " + "of guesses.");  
}
```

3> `String guessCount = 1;` The guessCount is string and you trying to assign integer. This is illegal.